# Adding/Removing from String kdb

Tags: kdb

I was doing some work to do with kdb and have been tinkering with strings and variables. I was just wondering if its possible to remove part of a string and add something to do the end of it.

```
s1:"Hello"  s2:" World"
```

I have a joint string "Hello World" which I created using

```
s3:s1,s2
```

I was trying to remove the Hello and add something after the World in the joint string.

```
s3[1*til 6] = Hello
```

This allows me to select the Hello part of the string if this helps

Comment: What solution did you try? You are already using comma to create s3 then you could use same for your other requirement. Instead of simply asking for answer, please also post your solution that you have tried.

Comment: s3[1*til 6],"Of Warcraft" is what I had tried

Comment: Cool. Try to mention your approach as well in your question that will help others to identify the root cause and to see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use drop (_) to get rid of the "Hello" and join (,) to add on what you want. Something like

```
q)6_s3,"star Hiphop"
"Worldstar Hiphop"
```

If you didn't want to count the letters in the first word you could use vector from scalar (vs) to get a list of enlisted words and index into it, then join onto that:

```
q)(" " vs s3)[1],"star Hiphop"
"Worldstar Hiphop"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are character lists, so the drop function `_` will still work on them. For example `1_"Hello"` will return `ello`.

So if you want to remove "Hello" from your string `s3` you would use

```
q)5_s3
"World"
```

Adding something onto the end of this then requires the join operator `,`, for example

```
q)s:"HelloWorld"
q)s1:"Mr. "
q)s2:5_s
q)s3:"wide"
q)s1,s2,s3
"Mr. Worldwide"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ssr function (string search replace).

```
q)s3:"HelloWorld"

q)ssr[s3;"Hello";""], " of War"
"World of War"
```